# js. check if array have a user-specified value thru prompt

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am a newbie in web-design, just learning now on CC. now trying to program my own js text game, in part of studying js. I am stuck with arrays.
I have a predefined array with strings, which need to be compared with user answer, but comparing did not doing.

```
    var myArray = ['selection 1', 'selection 2', 'selection 3', 'selection 4', 'selection 5', 'selection 6', 'selection 7', 'selection 8'];
    alert("text description of scene and dimensions"); 
    var dmg_start = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 1); // pre-start damage dimension, will be used further
    var user = prompt("make a selection").toLowerCase();
```

first idea, how to do it:

```
if (user.indexOf(myArray) > 0) {
console.log(user); // or mb document.write?
} else {
var user = prompt("make a selection").toLowerCase();
}
alert(myArray + "you can choose following");
```

second idea was:

```
    var find = function (myArray, user) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
             if (myArray[i] == user) {return i;
                 }
      }
       return null;
   };
```

third idea is:

```
do
{
    var user = prompt("make a selection").toLowerCase();
}
while (myArray.indexOf(user); // in idea, here must be checking for existence user given value in array
alert(myArray + "you can choose following");
```

also, I think it possible to do break after 1st wrong data input with alert
    alert(myArray + "you can choose following"); 
for help user make decision, then use continue loop.

in some cases i got two iterations of loop, then break loop, even if in loop user gives wrong (non contained in array) value.

but both were useless. which way can you suggest to solve this problem?

big thanks for your attention and helping me know more.

Comment: Just an extra. Prompting users with `promot()` and `alert()` is bad UX and should generally be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
var someArray = ['selection 1', 'selection 2', 'selection 3'];
var someIndex = -1;

do {
    var someUser = prompt("make a selection").toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
        if (someArray[i] === someUser) {
            someIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (someIndex > -1) {
        alert('found at index: ' + someIndex);
    } else {
        alert('not found: please try this...');
        // or something more put here
    }
}
while (someIndex === -1);
```

Comment: Your second example is vulnerable to errors in case `someObject[someUser]` is undefined

Comment: if it give a blank page in browser, it means, that code somewhere gone wrong? yes? so I tried to make same part as you suggested, but get white page. jshint show no errors.

Comment: Probably, post your page, let's take a look.

Comment: It's too simple, I think. all commited code are linked to defining which opt chosen in beginnig of code, so it is useless for now and non-ended.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/ocbnk7lx

Comment: Yes, the page is blank becuase there is no BODY. Add some content there and it will show on the page. I would also move the script to the last tag in the BODY element.

Comment: WhiteHat, thanks, tried your suggestion, this part works, but not how I meant. It returns position of someUser if it exists in array, but break if string not present in array. maybe something need to be corrected?

Comment: @WhiteHat. thanks a lot. your last suggestion is working fine and how I want it works) Chosen your answer as best.
All other, thanks for your time an suggestions. You're all make me know a little more

Answer (score 0):

Your condition fails if the user input is found at first location in the array.

```
if (user.indexOf(myArray) > 0) {
```

And

```
while (myArray.indexOf(user))
```

`indexOf()` gives `-1` if not found else `>= 0`.

**Edited: IST 09:11am 19 Jul 2015**

Try this example with loop for max 2 attempts:

```js
var fruits = ['apple', 'mangoe', 'grape'];
var cnt = 2; //max attempt
var inp; // for user input
var pos;
do {
  inp = prompt('Name a fruit').toLowerCase();
  pos = fruits.indexOf(inp);
  if (-1 === pos)
    alert('Fruits available: ' + fruits);
} while (--cnt); //upto max attempts
```

Comment: thanks for sharing. adoopted this loop, but explain me a bit more
   var opt = ['opt 1', 'opt 2', 'opt 3']; // some options
   alert("text"); 
   var pos = -1;
   var user; // for user input
   do {
   user = prompt('choose an option').toLowerCase();
   pos = opt.indexOf(user);
   } while (-1 !== pos);//not found within array
   alert(opt + "Avaliable options");
   user = prompt("make a choice").toLowerCase();
if place user = prompt below {} this loop do reqest for text 1st time before alert, second - after, no matter what input in.

Comment: Arvind, not exactly. Loop is just stopping to do if it does two times, no matter, what to input, correct or incorrect data.

Comment: WhiteHat, there is no problem with body of HTML, I just make a <script type="text/jscript" src="some_path/some_name.js"> reffer in html body, so it works, but with array and iteration is still have some problems. sorry for bothering you all, guys, but it is too interesting to me now)